# does "help" require an ing form?

Tags: grammar, verbs

A native English-speaker corrected my "help observing" with "help observe" in a written text:

> I provide a lens to help you observing the ants.

I cannot really see the rationale, as I would expect an action verb after "help".
Can you please help me understand/understanding why this is not the case?

Comment: He was correct. "Help" requires a _to_-infinitival clause as complement, but not a participial one.

Comment: @BillJ It doesn't require a to-infinitival.  It requires an infinitive - with or without *to*.  "...to help you to observe..." and "...to help you observe..." are both possible.

Comment: It's 'help you [to] observe' (verb) or 'help you _with_ observing' (gerund).

Comment: Note, all this is with "help" as a verb. If it were a noun, "I need help observing the ants," then the *-ing* is appropriate.

Comment: awesome, thanks for this! Special thanks to @AndyBonner, I could had easily made that mistake, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the verb **help** , we can use

> either *a bare infinitive* (infinitive without 'to') :
> *"I provide a lens to help you observe the ants."*

> or *a 'to' infinitive* (infinitive with 'to') :
> *"I provide a lens to help you to observe the ants."*

But we don't use *present participle* after it.

> *"I provide a lens to help you observing the ants."* (incorrect)

If you want to use *‘observing‘* as a noun (gerund), you can use it as *an object of a preposition* :

> *"I provide a lens to help you **in** / **with** observing the ants."*